# Double jump not working as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

that's my code to handle double jump.But sometimes it doesn't work.

First time I touch the screen my character jumps up ( variable doublejump = true ) . When I touch the screen a second time my character jumps higher(double jump = false)(double jump worked).

But sometimes when I touch the screen for the first time(no need to touch the screen a second time) doublejump variable = false(double jump not working as I expected)

Help me fix that

My code:

```
     void FixedUpdate ()
        {
            isGrounded = GroundedCheck ();
            if (gm.gameState == GameManager.GameState.playing) {

                foreach (GameObject g in gm.deadObjects) {
                    if (g.name == "P13") {
                        g.GetComponent<Mygroup> ().targetName = "P12";
                    } else if (g.name == "P12") {
                        g.GetComponent<Mygroup> ().targetName = "P11";
                    } else if (g.name == "P11") {
                        g.GetComponent<Mygroup> ().targetName = "P10";
                    } else if (g.name == "P10") {
                        g.GetComponent<Mygroup> ().targetName = "P9";
                    } else if (g.name == "P9") {
                        g.GetComponent<Mygroup> ().targetName = "P8";
                    } else if (g.name == "P8") {
                        g.GetComponent<Mygroup> ().targetName = "P7";
                    } else if (g.name == "P7") {
                        g.GetComponent<Mygroup> ().targetName = "P6";
                    } else if (g.name == "P6") {
                        g.GetComponent<Mygroup> ().targetName = "P5";
                    } else if (g.name == "P5") {
                        g.GetComponent<Mygroup> ().targetName = "P4";
                    } else if (g.name == "P4") {
                        g.GetComponent<Mygroup> ().targetName = "P3";
                    } else if (g.name == "P3") {
                        g.GetComponent<Mygroup> ().targetName = "P2";
                    } else if (g.name == "P2") {
                        g.GetComponent<Mygroup> ().targetName = "P1";
                    } else if (g.name == "P1") {
                        g.GetComponent<Mygroup> ().targetName = "P0";
                    } else if (g.name == "P0") {
                        g.GetComponent<Mygroup> ().targetName = null;
                    }
                }
                if (this.gameObject.name == "P0") {
                    targetName = "";
                } else if (this.gameObject.name == "P1")
                    targetName = "P0";
                else if (this.gameObject.name == "P2")
                    targetName = "P1";
                else if (this.gameObject.name == "P3")
                    targetName = "P2";
                else if (this.gameObject.name == "P4")
                    targetName = "P3";
                else if (this.gameObject.name == "P5")
                    targetName = "P4";
                else if (this.gameObject.name == "P6")
                    targetName = "P5";
                else if (this.gameObject.name == "P7")
                    targetName = "P6";
                else if (this.gameObject.name == "P8")
                    targetName = "P7";
                else if (this.gameObject.name == "P9")
                    targetName = "P8";
                else if (this.gameObject.name == "P10")
                    targetName = "P9";
                else if (this.gameObject.name == "P11")
                    targetName = "P10";
                else if (this.gameObject.name == "P12")
                    targetName = "P11";

                target = GameObject.Find (targetName);

                if (isGrounded) {
                    jumping = false;
                    doubleJump = false;
                    jumpAnim = false;

    if (this.gameObject.name == "P0" && isGrounded && !doubleJump && !jumping) {
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && this.gameObject.name == "P0") {
                        jumping = true;
                        rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 50f * jump, 0);
                        doubleJump = true;
                    }
                }
    if (this.gameObject.name == "P0" && !isGrounded && doubleJump && jumping) {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && this.gameObject.name == "P0") {
                        rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 60f * jump, 0);
                        doubleJump = false;
                    }
                }

if (target != null && this.gameObject.name != "P0" && isGrounded && target.GetComponent<Mygroup> ().doubleJump && !target.GetComponent<Mygroup> ().isGrounded) {
                    StartCoroutine (Jump ());
                }

    if (target != null && this.gameObject.name != "P0" && !isGrounded && doubleJump && !target.GetComponent<Mygroup> ().isGrounded && !target.GetComponent<Mygroup> ().doubleJump) {
                    StartCoroutine (JumpDouble ());
                }
        }
        IEnumerator Jump ()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (time);

            if (gameObject.name == "P1")
                rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 49.6f * jump, 0);
            if (gameObject.name == "P2")
                rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 49.4f * jump, 0);
            if (gameObject.name == "P3")
                rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 49.2f * jump, 0);
            if (gameObject.name == "P4")
                rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 49f * jump, 0);
            if (gameObject.name == "P5")
                rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 48.8f * jump, 0);
            if (gameObject.name == "P6")
                rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 48.6f * jump, 0);
            if (gameObject.name == "P7")
                rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 48.4f * jump, 0);
            if (gameObject.name == "P8")
                rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 48.2f * jump, 0);
            if (gameObject.name == "P9")
                rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 48f * jump, 0);
            if (gameObject.name == "P10")
                rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 47.8f * jump, 0);
            if (gameObject.name == "P11")
                rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 47.6f * jump, 0);
            if (gameObject.name == "P12")
                rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 47.4f * jump, 0);

            jumping = true;
            doubleJump = true;

        }
        IEnumerator JumpDouble ()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (time);
            if (doubleJump) {

                if (gameObject.name == "P1")
                    rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 59.8f * jump, 0);
                if (gameObject.name == "P2")
                    rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 59.6f * jump, 0);
                if (gameObject.name == "P3")
                    rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 59.4f * jump, 0);
                if (gameObject.name == "P4")
                    rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 59.2f * jump, 0);
                if (gameObject.name == "P5")
                    rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 59f * jump, 0);
                if (gameObject.name == "P6")
                    rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 58.8f * jump, 0);
                if (gameObject.name == "P7")
                    rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 58.6f * jump, 0);
                if (gameObject.name == "P8")
                    rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 58.4f * jump, 0);
                if (gameObject.name == "P9")
                    rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 58.2f * jump, 0);
                if (gameObject.name == "P10")
                    rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 58f * jump, 0);
                if (gameObject.name == "P11")
                    rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 57.8f * jump, 0);
                if (gameObject.name == "P12")
                    rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 57.6f * jump, 0);
                doubleJump = false;
                jumping = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you set `doubleJump` & `jumping` to false again when you reach the ground?

Comment: Yes i do
 if (isGrounded) {
    jumping = false;
    doubleJump = false;

Comment: It that case the `jumping` variable doesn't actually do anything in the blocks o code you've posted & you can take it out. `if (this.gameObject.name == "P0" && isGrounded && !doubleJump && !jumping)` could be `if (this.gameObject.name == "P0" && isGrounded)` with the exact same function

Comment: My problem is my code worked but sometimes it fails and I really do not know why

Comment: I see this post is already quite a few weeks old, but since it doesn't have a real answer yet I suggest you fix the formatting of your code so people can read it better. Also I think this is a lot of code to execute every frame, since you have a lot of if statements. Reducing that redundancy enhances readability and performance.

Comment: Sory i still can't fix my problem :). But thanks for help

Comment: That's why I recommend you to fix the formatting of your code, so other people can help you fixing your problem. The formatting is mostly the indentations that got messed up when you pasted your code. Although C# does not need indentation for compiling and executing code, it is very important for humans who try to read it.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to use two variables 'doubleJump & jumping'
Might this work, check following one

```
if (this.gameObject.name == "P0" && isGrounded && !jumping) {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
                jumping = true;
                rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 50f * jump, 0);
            }
        }


if (this.gameObject.name == "P0" && !isGrounded && jumping) {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
                rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 60f * jump, 0);
                jumping = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I use two variables doublejump  and  jump because I am make a game like Zombie tsunami. And my idea is the subject of my first (P0) jump up, then the objects behind (P1, P2, ... Pn) will turn to jump after the first object I've edited my code above

Comment: My problem is my code worked but sometimes it fails and I really do not know why

Comment: We can write different type of code for same problem right, like that try writing code in some other manner then check Is working properly, I don't have unity to work on now, sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (this.gameObject.name == "P0" && !isGrounded && doubleJump && jumping) {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && this.gameObject.name == "P0") {
                    rid.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 60f * jump, 0);
                    doubleJump = false;
```

My suggestion is that you remove '&& jumping' from your if statement. 
Hope it helps.

Cheers.